# Cannot add STRING_AGG(column, ',') into overall Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2017 and my query works perfectly fine, with the exception of when I try to add the following:

> ,STRING_AGG (TemplateID, ',') as Result1

This is a Stored Procedure supporting an SSRS report in the end.

I need the templateID's to be in a result which would be a comma separated list of values like "1,3,5,12,14,33,44,100,107" (just as an example) Also like to only select Distinct ones if possible.

When I add the above to my overall Stored Procedure, I get the following error in Management Studio:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_ChangesByUserDetail, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 7]
> Column 'ChangeDetail.DisplayName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Here is my entire SELECT statement.

```
SELECT DisplayName, IsDeleted, TemplateID,TemplateName, Version, Name, UpdatedBy, DataTable, ID, IsVirtual,
DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate) As AddedDate,
CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate), 108)
AS AddedTime, AttachmentContent, UserName, UpdatedDate,
cast(datediff(second, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', AddedDate) as varchar ) + '000' as millisec
,STRING_AGG (TemplateID, ',') as Result1

FROM ChangeDetail  WITH (NOLOCK) 
where UpdatedBy in (select s from fn_SplitLarge(',',@In_ModifiedBy)) 
and templatename in (select s from fn_SplitLarge(',',@In_ItemType)) 

and DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate) between  @In_StartDate + @In_StartTime and @In_EndDate + @In_EndTime
```

Thoughts?

Comment: `string_agg()` is an aggregation function.  You need to use it with `group by` -- just like `max()` or `sum()`.

Comment: I've been reading for hours, and saw some stuff around this, but I cannot get it through my head.

Comment: Simplify.  Start with a much simpler source table, and desired results.  It makes no sense to concatenate TemplateIDs in that query as each TemplateID is on a seperate row.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, but over my head. Was just looking for what I thought was something simple(ish) ... appears it might need an overhaul. ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is not having the fields grouped by. Also note that the field for which you group by shouldn't be in the list of fields (and the Name)

ex.

```
Create table #t (Id int, TemplateName varchar(100))
insert into #t values
(1,'aaa'), (1,'bbb'),(1,'ccc'),(2,'ppp'),(2,'qqq'),(3,'XXX'),(3,'YYY'),(4,'ZZZ  ')

SELECT ID, TemplateName  FROM #T

-- FOLLOWING DOESN'T WORK
-- SELECT ID, TemplateName, STRING_AGG (TemplateName, ',') as Result1   FROM #T

-- FOLLOWING WORKS
SELECT ID, STRING_AGG (TemplateName, ',') as Result1   FROM #T
GROUP BY ID
```

So you can make your query as follows:

```
Select DisplayName, IsDeleted, Version, Name, UpdatedBy, DataTable, ID, IsVirtual,
    AddedDate,AddedTime, AttachmentContent, UserName, UpdatedDate, millisec
    ,STRING_AGG (TemplateID, ',') as Result1 
from
(
    SELECT DisplayName, IsDeleted, TemplateID,TemplateName, Version, Name, UpdatedBy, DataTable, ID, IsVirtual,
            DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate) As AddedDate,
            CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate), 108) AS AddedTime, 
            AttachmentContent, UserName, UpdatedDate,
            cast(datediff(second, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', AddedDate) as varchar ) + '000' as millisec
    FROM ChangeDetail  WITH (NOLOCK) 
    where UpdatedBy in (select s from fn_SplitLarge(',',@In_ModifiedBy)) 
        and templatename in (select s from fn_SplitLarge(',',@In_ItemType)) 
        and DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, getutcdate(), GETDATE()), AddedDate) 
            between  @In_StartDate + @In_StartTime and @In_EndDate + @In_EndTime
) Q
Group By DisplayName, IsDeleted, Version, Name, UpdatedBy, DataTable, ID, IsVirtual,
    AddedDate,AddedTime, AttachmentContent, UserName, UpdatedDate, millisec
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There is a random "Q" just before Group By which a typo I assume, and when I try to run it, I get  "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_ChangesByUserDetail, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 7]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'. " I'm working through it ...

Comment: Q is not random that or any other alias is a must. Did you check my example and try understanding the usage of `STRING_AGG`

Comment: hmm ok, with the "Q" I now get:   "Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_ChangesByUserDetail, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 7]
The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Comment: That is a different issue. Check for any such field, as text and convert to varchar(max). most probably `AttachmentContent`

Comment: Found the "text" column, all sorted. Thanks VERY much !

Comment: that worked, as in no errors and a value was returned. The issue now is only a single value is returned in Result1 , and not a comma separated list of all the values for that column that exist in the current resultset ;( Thoughts ?

Comment: ‍@Vacek, cannot exactly say much, as I don't have any sample data to test. Most probably the data may be one record per TemplateID. Edit your question and post some sample data in ChangeDetail . I will write the query without the Where condition